# Multiple errors with UIActivityViewController in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

When I run the code below, a lot of strange errors are output to the console. If you read them, you will notice that they are all referred to some "database" and "retrieving thubnail". I guessing it's somehow   linked with non ordinary type of document i tried to share (Excel sheet). Is there any hint how can i avoid this mess or maybe solve the problem?

Console output:

```
2021-12-11 02:01:40.253894+0300 dia[964:95878] [Fetching] LPFileMetadataProviderSpecialization failed to retrieve a thumbnail from QuickLookThumbnailing (Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=0 "Could not generate a thumbnail")
2021-12-11 02:01:40.267006+0300 dia[964:95858] [default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
2021-12-11 02:01:40.267062+0300 dia[964:95858] [default] Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
2021-12-11 02:01:40.267105+0300 dia[964:95858] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
2021-12-11 02:01:40.268634+0300 dia[964:95858] [default] -imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)
2021-12-11 02:01:40.276320+0300 dia[964:95858] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-12-11 02:01:40.512236+0300 dia[964:95858] [default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
2021-12-11 02:01:40.512331+0300 dia[964:95858] [default] Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
2021-12-11 02:01:40.512396+0300 dia[964:95858] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
2021-12-11 02:01:40.512597+0300 dia[964:95858] [default] -imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)
2021-12-11 02:01:40.518850+0300 dia[964:95858] [LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionReusableView that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIActivityContentFooterView: 0x1021589b0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (20 482.5; 374 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x28133d660>>
```

My full code:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct export: View {
  @State private var isPres: Bool = false
  @State private var isLoad: Bool = true
  @State private var path: [Any] = []
  var anatomy = Anatomy()
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      VStack {
        ScrollView {
          HStack {
            Button(action:{
              isLoad.toggle()
              Task {
                path.removeAll()
                path.append(try await anatomy.generate())
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.20) {
                  isLoad.toggle()
                }
              }
              isPres.toggle()
            }){
              VStack{
                Image("menu_xlsx")
                Text("Показать данные в \n таблице").foregroundColor(Color.black).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
              }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPres) {
              ShareSheet(activityItems: path)
            }
            Button(action:{}){
              VStack{
                Image("menu_mail")
                Text("Отправить данные \n врачу").foregroundColor(Color.black).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
              }
            }
          }.padding(.top)
        }
        Spacer()
      }
      if !isLoad {
        ProgressView()
          .progressViewStyle(.circular)
          .scaleEffect(2.5)
      }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Экспорт данных")
  }
}

struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
//  typealias Callback = (_ activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, _ completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void

  let activityItems: [Any]
  let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
//  let excludedActivityTypes: [UIActivity.ActivityType]? = nil
//  let callback: Callback? = nil
   
  func makeUIViewController(context: Self.Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
    let controller = UIActivityViewController(
      activityItems: activityItems,
      applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
//    controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes
//    controller.completionWithItemsHandler = callback
    return controller
  }
   
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Self.Context) {
    // nothing to do here
  }
}

struct export_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    export()
  }
}
```

Comment: You might find next helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/69694099/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59433735/12299030. I did not get any errors.

Comment: I get the same error when I try to share a file with a custom Type Identifier (custom extension) because it don't founds the thumb icon for this file. The icon should be included in the app bundle and the file name should be set the in Info.plist file. But it still show the warning, maybe it is a Info.plist file cache.

Comment: You can find how to set custom file icon here https://www.raywenderlich.com/813044-uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial-sharing-data

Comment: @ims, so that the solution, thx.