# SwiftUI 4: ShareLink as a swipe action

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list, ios-sharesheet

I would like to present a share sheet when the user interacts with a swipe action.
To achieve this I currently have simply this code:

```
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                ShareLink("Text", item: "Text")
                    .tint(.accentColor)
            }
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

but when I tap it, nothing happens...

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open Share Sheet from presented sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693871/how-to-open-share-sheet-from-presented-sheet)

Comment: Not directly, but it also works...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but I found the sollution:

```
.swipeActions(){
Button(action: {
let url = URL(string: "your url here")
let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url!], applicationActivities: nil)

UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)
}) {
Label("", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
}
```

Hope it works for you :)